# Channels in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Are channels only created in hyperledger fabric only when the business network is deployed ? Or it can be created afterwards. If yes than how it is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Channels are a hyperledger fabric concept and not a hyperledger composer concept. A business network will be instantiated on a channel. So the channel must already have been created using the standard fabric mechanisms for creating channels.

Answer (score -1):

It is able to create a new channel in an existing orderer, and then ask existing peers to join that channel.

On Fabric Node.js SDK, we can use `Channel.createChannel()` and `Channel.joinChannel()` to do it.

related references:

- https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.3/Client.html#createChannel
- https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.3/Channel.html#joinChannel

Hope this helps.